# Estimation method to find unknown operators in an equation

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I saw in a riddles game the expression
$$8?4?6=6?7?4$$
where each $?$ was to be replaced with one of $+-×÷$ to make the equation valid.

I solved it by intuition, but, is there any estimation method, even for more easy equations, to help solve this kind of riddles? I've googled, but found anything but classic equations resolutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just out of curiosity,  what is your solution ?

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what you mean by "estimation method"?

Comment: @callculus  8*4+6=6*7-4

Comment: @Couchy311 Excuse me, as English is not my first language. I mean any mathematical method to determine what one or more of the operators could be, for the equation to be valid.

Comment: @lljorgero Guess and Check *shrug*

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @transcenmental, it is pretty much guess-and-check, but you can sometimes narrow down the possibilities by using GCF or LCM or working backwards (for the equations that have a given answer already on one side).
But for yours, its guess-and-check.